# Deleting an Edited Message using DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I am facing the Problem of my DiscordJS Bot not deleting an Edited Message.

```js
client.on("messageUpdate", (newMessage, oldMessage) => {
  if (
    config.filter_list.some(word =>
      newMessage.content.toUpperCase().includes(word)
    )
  ) {
    newMessage.delete();
  }
});
```

This is the code I am using which, sadly, doesn't work.
However, the Bot does Delete Messages when first sent using this script:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
  } else if (
    config.filter_list.some(word =>
      message.content.toUpperCase().includes(word)
    )
  )
    message.delete();
});
```

I am grateful for any Help.

Regards,
Luis

Comment: The event will only trigger for messages in cache, so if you edit a message from before you started the bot, it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you switched newMessage and oldMessage. Try the following:

```
    client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
    if (config.filter_list.some(word => newMessage.content.toUpperCase().includes(word))) 
    {
      newMessage.delete()
    }
    });
```